# Electric flow rate (Amper) on the com-port

Tags: computers, interface, education

I have sending data through com-port from PC. 
Is there a constant rate of flow of electric charge (Ampere) when the com-port is used while sending or not sending data through it? Does the Ampere on the com-port depends on the data being sent? If I don't send data from PC will the rate of flow become less?

I am asking it because I have connected the 3rd (transmit pin) and 5th(ground pin) of com-port (with 9 pins) to the lamp. And it is shining when I am constantly sending data from PC to this port. If I am not sending data the lamp stops shining. Also, if I am sending 0x00 value constantly the lamp is shining brightly. If I am sending 0xFF then it is not so bright. 
Can u explain it?

EDIT1:

The Voltage is the same when I am sendning data or not between the 3 and 5th pins. However the lamp is not shining when the data is not being sent, but only when it is being sent. How is it possible? The voltage is about 5-6V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should always be about 12V between pins 3 and 5 of the serial port, it's just the polarity that changes one way for a 0, the other for a 1. Usually when the port is quiet, TxD (pin 3) rides at about -12V relative to GND (pin 5). While the RS-232 spec actually allows for anything from -3 to -15, I don't think I've ever encountered a PC serial port that wasn't in the neighborhood of 12V.

An ordinary light connected to this should be on all the time. However, there is also usually a current limiting resistor in series with TxD that should keep the current quite small, which won't light an ordinary lamp. I suspect your lamp is in fact an LED.

With the variable brightness, you have discovered duty cycle; the more 0 bits in the data, the brighter the light. Whenever you transmit data, zero bits are represented by TxD swinging to the other polarity, and with an LED, this means, no light. The order of the bits isn't terribly critical. 0x0F and 0xF0 and 0xAA and 0x55 should be all about the same brightness.

Comment: Yes, may be it is a LED. Can you explain more about the duty cycle? What happens to the LED when I dont send any data? What confuses me is the fact, that the measurements of the voltage shows about 5 or 6 V when the data is being sent and when it is not sent. However in one case (when the data is being set, the LED is ON, otherwise it is OFF).

Comment: @maximus - if you reverse the leads on the light, and the brightness-vs-output-value relationship reverses, it's an LED. When you're not sending any data, pin 3 idles at about -12V relative to pin 5. Not quite sure why your measurement would come out at 5 or 6 no matter what. More information about your meter and how you're probing would help.